# Плагин Qt не может инициализироваться

Tags: python, pyside6

Когда только начинал изучать PySide6, была такая же проблема, но я её решил, вытащив папку platforms прямо в папку, где лежит Python. Позже я написал какую-то программку и захотел её конвертировать в exe. Запускаю и вылазит опять это же окошко с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: platforms должна лежать в каталоге с программой

Comment: а куда именно, вместе с exe файлом?